# Is the CRM 2011 IOrganizationService.SaveChanges() method, processed in transaction?

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have used the CRM 2011 SDK tool to generate classes for early-bound entities.
My requirement consists of a Debit-Credit scenario.
Therefore if one create object fails, the other must be rolled back.

I cannot find information on whether the method above, performs the operation in a transaction.

Can anyone confirm?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Depends how you are executing the create calls.

Externally, e.g. from a console application. Then no it doesn't. The ability to make a transaction call from an external application was introduced in CRM 2015/2016.

[Sample: Execute multiple requests in transaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt634414.aspx)

> **Microsoft Dynamics 365 (online & on-premises) support batching of
>   requests into a single web service method call.** Each request in the
>   batch is executed as part of a single database transaction. **Failure of
>   any request to complete successfully causes a rollback of any
>   completed requests** and no further processing is performed on requests
>   not yet executed.

If you are executing inside of a plugin, then your create calls may be included in a transaction, dependent on the registration of your plugin.

[Inclusion in Database Transactions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327941(v=crm.5).aspx#bkmk_DatabaseTransactions)

> **Plug-ins may or may not execute within the database transaction** of the
>   Microsoft Dynamics CRM platform. Whether a plug-in is part of the
>   transaction is dependent on how the message request is processed by
>   the pipeline. You can check if the plug-in is executing in-transaction
>   by reading the IsInTransaction property inherited by
>   IPluginExecutionContext that is passed to the plug-in. **If a plug-in is
>   executing in the database transaction and allows an exception to be
>   passed back to the platform, the entire transaction will be rolled
>   back. Stages 20 and 40 are guaranteed to be part of the database
>   transaction** while stage 10 and 50 may be part of the transaction.
>
> Any registered plug-in that executes during the database transaction
>   and that passes an exception back to the platform cancels the core
>   operation. This results in a rollback of the core operation. In
>   addition, any pre-event or post event registered plug-ins that have
>   not yet executed and any workflow that is triggered by the same event
>   that the plug-in was registered for will not execute.